# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql' for database adapter,

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run rake db:setup for my old rails project and it is throwing the following error.

```
`rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).


Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.

Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`
```

this is my ruby version `ruby 2.3.8p459 (2018-10-18 revision 65136) [x86_64-linux]`

my rails version `Rails 4.2.7.1`

and mysql version `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.56, for linux-glibc2.5 (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Thank you

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding line that specifies that the adapter is mysql2 (and not mysql)

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Instead of

```
adapter: mysql
```

in your config/database.yml file

If just the above does not work then update your Gemfile and explicitly add activerecord-mysql2-adapter dependency there:

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

Comment: hello,
thank you for your replay.
after change the adapter and add gems to gemfile,
now i am getting the following errors.
`#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)>`